# In javascript how do I refer to this.form.checkbox[5].checked?

Tags: javascript, arrays, onchange

I have a series of checkboxes and input type="text" areas, wherein I need to have the state of the checkbox set to true when the value in the text area changes.  Simple enough.  I've done this successfully:

```
<input name="fixed" type="checkbox">
<input name="stuff" type="text" onchange="this.form.fixed.checked=true">
```

Which works fine.  You have to edit the field then click out of it, but that is fine for my needs:

...but when I switch to this:

```
<input name="fixed[0]" type="checkbox">
<input name="stuff" type="text" onchange="this.form.fixed[0].checked=true">
<input name="fixed[1]" type="checkbox">
<input name="stuff" type="text" onchange="this.form.fixed[1].checked=true">
```

I get no change to my checkboxes when I edit:

My only javascript know-how comes from googling this sort of thing, I'm afraid.  Anyone have any better info on this than the Oracle of Google on The Mountain has in store?

thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Switch from dot notation to bracket notation!

```
this.form['fixed[0]'].checked
```

Comment: Cheers!  One quick change in my rails view (it just generates raw text to the client, so I left that out in my question) nailed it first time!

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you're mixing some shady practices in HTML, and when you do it in javascript, they're breaking.

So this.form.fixed[1] in javascript really says "The second item in the array this.form.fixed.  So I think that's the problem.  try naming your elements fixed0 and fixed1 and see if that works.

**Edit**: You could also use bracket notation, as illustrated by Peter, which should solve the problem without editing the names of the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Make life easier on yourself.

Create unique ID's for the elements you are trying to reference and refer to them from the elements to which you bind your events:

```
<input name="fixed[0]" type="checkbox" id="fixed_0">
<input name="stuff" type="text" onchange="document.getElementById('fixed_0').checked=true">
<input name="fixed[1]" type="checkbox" id="fixed_1">
<input name="stuff" type="text" onchange="document.getElementById('fixed_1').checked=true">
```